# Slowly fade to black on death

Tags: c, opengl, fade

I have been trying to make a function that slowly fades to black once the player dies. I have everything setup (fading, etc...), but I don't know how to make an OpenGL color mask or whatever it takes to actually fade the screen to black.

I have tried using glClearColor and then glClear, but the results were just completely black. I know that it would *technically* be possible to do so by editing each color attribute of my code dynamically, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler way.

Comment: Reduce the alpha over time?

Comment: @Aesthete yeah, that's what I'm trying to do. I just don't know how to do that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple way might be to draw a single quad over the entire viewport after drawing everything else.  You could draw it black with an alpha value and use a blend function to let the alpha value determine how much of the black to use.  You would probably want to disable depth testing.

Comment: wow, I feel pretty dumb right now. Thanks, I'll try that! Will set it as correct once I am sure it works (would be surprised if it doesn't though)